# Memory leak in Pushing view controller

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, navigationcontroller

In Instrument-Leaks, the following code increasing Allocation memory always, when ever i am pushing **PhotosObj** .Releasing **PhotosObj** is not working.

```
if (PhotosObj) {
    [PhotosObj release];
    PhotosObj=nil;
    PhotosObj=[[Photos alloc]initWithNibName:@"Photos" bundle:nil]; 
}
else {
    PhotosObj=[[Photos alloc]initWithNibName:@"Photos" bundle:nil];
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:PhotosObj animated:YES];
```

Please clarify me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

What kind of variable is PhotosObj?  Local, global, or instance variable?
I recommend to make it a local variable (and variable name should start with a small letter) like this:

```
Photos *photosObj = [[Photos alloc] initWithNibName:@"Photos" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:photosObj animated:YES];
[photosObj release];
```

Comment: @boopathi have you released that photosObj's object

Comment: @kamarshad  yes,but still leak is there.It seems like releasing photosObj is not working .If i push same object,the leak is not there

Comment: @boopathi if you used hoshi's Code ..?.then it'll not show any memory leaks.because he managed the memory properly.

Comment: @kamarshad can you give me hoshi's Code details? it will be fine for me.

Comment: @boopathi come on chat so that we can discuss that easily.
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad